# CSS background Image responsive scaling

Tags: css, responsive-design, wordpress-theming, background-image

I know there are alot of questions for the same topic but I have tried almost everything to get it work but did not succeed.

I am working on a WP theme and I have a header background image which does not scale properly when on mobile/smaller screens.

If anyone can help me scaling for that image.

Also, as this image will be a dynamic image, should I use an image tag or inline css background image?

For a reference, please have a look on the following link.

[header background scaling](http://beta.eliteacademyqatar.com)

Comment: How much height you need on mobile devices ??

Comment: full screen as in desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "background-size" property of css? 
If yes, how did you gave the values in it? in percentage or in hardcoded px because this solution works perfectly for background images. In your header's css or wherever you are having this image, do it like this, or you an specify your own percentage values according to your requirement:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

If it doesn't work, let me know or if possible, please share the code so that I can guide you better. Hope this will help.

Cheers!!!

Comment: I did what you suggested. It does the trick. the only issue i get in this solution is the ratio is is lost. see [link](https://ibb.co/iU7n8S). Also, I have shared the link of live page in my question

Comment: For that purpose, you can try as follows:

`background-size: contain;`

but this will repeat the image on y-axis. For that issue, you can do:

`background-repeat: no-repeat;`

But then your image will be in perfectly ratio but it'd be leaving spaces from top and bottom. So conclusion is you have to change image pixels manually or through some tool like Photoshop. Then it'll fit the screen wherever you want to open it.
Hope it helps :)